# Pyinstaller - Failed to execute script pyi_rth__tkinter

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, pyinstaller

I'm trying to convert my Python tkinter notepad to exe with pyinstaller.
But when I open created exe file i get error:

```
Failed to execute script pyi_rth__tkinter
```

I tried changing pyinstaller version to 5.0 developer from github and importing pkg_resources.py2_warn but that didn't work and I get the same error.
I'm using python 3.9.1
Here's my code:

```
  from tkinter import *
from tkinter import filedialog
from PIL import ImageTk
from PIL import Image


root = Tk()
root.geometry("600x375")
root.resizable(False, False)
root.title("NetNote")
root.iconbitmap("ikona.ico")
#liczba globalna zapisz
global open_status_name
open_status_name = False





def usuwanie():
    text.delete(1.0, END)
    global open_status_name
    open_status_name = False
    

def open_txt():
 
    text_file = filedialog.askopenfilename(title="Open Text File", filetypes=(("Text Files", "*.txt"),))
    if text_file:
        global open_status_name
        open_status_name = text_file
    text_file = open(text_file, "r")
    stuff = text_file.read()
    text.delete("1.0", END)
    text.insert(END, stuff)
    text_file.close()
#fukcja - save as
def save_as():
    text_file=filedialog.asksaveasfilename(defaultextension=".*", title="Zapisz jako", filetypes=(("Text Files", "*.txt"),))
    if text_file:
        name = text_file
        name = name.replace("","") 
        text_file = open(text_file, "w")
        text_file.write(text.get(1.0, END))
        text_file.close()


def save_file():
    global open_status_name
    if open_status_name:
        text_file = open(open_status_name, "w")
        text_file.write(text.get(1.0, END))
        text_file.close()
    else:
        save_as()

    
    
   

frame = LabelFrame(root, text="Menu",padx=2, pady=2)
frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=S, padx=10, pady=10)



my_logo = Image.open("logo.png")

resized = my_logo.resize((110, 138), Image.ANTIALIAS)
my_logo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(file="logo.png")
new_pic = ImageTk.PhotoImage(resized)


my_label = Label(root, image=new_pic)
my_label.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=N, pady=20)



przycisk1 = Button(frame, text="Nowy",width=8, height=1, command=usuwanie,)
przycisk1.grid(row=0,column=0, sticky=N, padx=10, pady=10,)




przycisk2 = Button(frame, text="Otwórz", width=8,height=1, command=open_txt)
przycisk2.grid(row=1, column=0,)
root.mainloop



przycisk3 = Button(frame, text="Zapisz jako", width=8,height=1,command=save_as)
przycisk3.grid(row=2, column=0, padx=10, pady=10)



text = Text(root, height=20, width=57, font=("Calibri, 11"))
text.grid(row=0, column=1, padx=10, pady=10)



przycisk4 = Button(frame, text="Zapisz", width=8, height=1, command=save_file)
przycisk4.grid(row=3, column=0, pady=(0, 10))


root.mainloop
```

Comment: make sure that images like ```ikona.ico``` and other in the same folder with .exe file

Comment: Yes, I tried that but I still get the same error

Comment: As I remeber documentation for `pyinstaller` has information how to add extra files `resources` to .exe. It has also page `"when it goes wrong"`. So first read documentation. (PL: najpierw sprawdź dokumentacje `pyinstallera`)

Comment: first run in console to see full error message. And always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information.

Comment: every variable created outside function is global - so using `global open_status_name` outside function is useless. We use `global` inside function to inform function that it has to assign value (`=`) to external/global variable instead of creating local variable.

Comment: there is good rule to keep all `global` at the beginning of function. There is also good rule to keep all functions after imports - it means before `root = Tk()`. This makes code more readable. See more in: [PEP 8 -- Style Guide for PythonCod](https://ww.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)

Comment: I checked pyinstaller documentation and I didn't find any solve for this problem. I also added files while creating exe but i still get same error:
`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Pawliee\Documents\python\Lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\hooks\rthooks\pyi_rth__tkinter.py", line 28, in <module>
    raise FileNotFoundError('Tcl data directory "%s" not found.' % (tcldir))
FileNotFoundError: Tcl data directory "C:\Users\Pawliee\Documents\python\python projekty\test tkinter\dist\tkinter\tcl" not found.

[4676] Failed to execute script pyi_rth__tkinter`

Answer (score 0):

You can try this method:

`pyinstaller --onefile -w`

Even I had created a notepad using Tkinter, and this method did the work for me

Comment: Did this work? If it does not work, try cx_Freeze

Comment: I still get same error but now in windowed mode. I will try use cx_freeze.